# Value of transcendental function $f(x)$ at rational point $a$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry

$f(x)$ is a transcendental function over $\mathbb{Q}(x)$,and analytic in disk with natural boundary. If $a\gt 0$ and $a\in \mathbb{Q}$, then $f(a)$ is a transcendental number.

Has this assertion been proved? Any reference?

Update base on comments: $f(x)$ is a transcendental function over $\mathbb{Q}(x)$,and analytic in disk with natural boundary. If $a\gt 0$,and $a\neq 1$ and $a\in \mathbb{Q}$, then $f(a)$ is a transcendental number.

Has this assertion been proved? Any reference?

Comment: Sort of. There are some [theorems with that flavor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem). And [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

Comment: What is your definition of transcendental function?

Comment: @DanielLittlewood [Well known definition existing even before the modern definition of functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_function)

Comment: It sounds like a theorem, and is more generalized than Gelfond theorem, I am not sure if any one has proved such a theorem, or we can give one now.

Comment: False. E.g. the principal branch of $\log z$ for $|z-1|<1.$ We have $\log 1=0.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet thank you for your comment, my question has been updated based on your comment.

Comment: It looks like simple, but I do not know how to prove or refute it.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet and in fact $log z$ has no natural boundary.

Comment: Try  $f(x)=e^{x^2-4}$ and $x=2$.

Comment: The natural boundary thing doesn't look like a condition related to transcendence of the values. Just take $f(x)=x\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{x^{n!}}{n!}$. For this function $f(0)=0$.

Comment: @lulu Good hehe

Comment: @lulu actually, your function is not with natural boundary.

Comment: @Bettybel natural boundary has to be a condition, otherwise, lulu's example is a counterexample.

Comment: I am unclear as to what is meant by a natural boundary. But if the function $f(x)$ is transcendental over $Q(x)$ and f is not constant then  so is $g(x)=f(x)-f(x_0)$ for any $x_0\in dom (f) .$  So choose some rational $x_0.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet for natural boudary see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalBoundary.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g$ be any transcendental function over $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ with the unit circle as natural boundary (or whatever reasonable assumption you want to put). Since $g$ is not constant, $g$ assumes some value that is algebraic at some point in the disc, say $g(a) = x$ where $x$ is algebraic.

Define
$$
f(z) = g(m(z))
$$
where $m$ is a biholomorphic automorphism of the disk taking some rational positive number $r$ to $a$. Then $f(r) = x$, so in general this fails for a very large class of transcendental functions.